# converting static html menus to wordpress dynamic menus keeping the style same

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

ok so here is my static html menu..

```
 <ul id="nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="index.html"><span>Home</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span>Holiday Packages</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span>Best Deals</span></a>
                </ul>
```

css for span --- >

```
#nav a span { background:url(images/nav-right.png) right top no-repeat; padding:0 26px 0 0; display:block; }
```

problem is how can i apply my span styling to dynamically generated menu because wp_nav_menu();
output the following ----->

```
<a href="#">Holiday Packages</a>
```

leaving me no option to apply span tag to "Holiday Packages" which is a menu item ..

Answer (score 0):

Simply set : You can't simply do that with CSS.

You can probably, though, edit Wordpress templates which are generating menu to make them add spans inside the `a` elements.

That shouldn't be really hard.

Comment: Shouldn't be really hard, typo, sorry :p

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Wordpress' menu function: [wp_nav_menu()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu)

You can read up on how to style your menu (and it's different levels) here: http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-style-wordpress-navigation-menus/

Answer (score 0):

You can manupulate item_wrap to get the thing done.
Here is the link that should kickstart you. 
Go here and search for this phrase "Adding a Word at the Beginning of the Menu"

link is [HERE](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/)